# Unable to call child function via tkinter button in python

Tags: python, tkinter

In GUI, when I click step1 button it is assign value to self.p1 then I click step2 which should call child function which will use self.p1 value generated from step1.

But I am getting error at step 2, if i use instance then it executing step1 even before clicking the button.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

def neighbor():

    n1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("n1",n1)
    return n1

class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.p1 = neighbor()
        print("p1",self.p1)

    def child(self):
        print("c1", self.p1)

root=tkinter.Tk()
root.title("test")
root.geometry("400x300")

#instance = parent()
#instance.child()

b=Button(root,text='step1',bg='green',command=Parent,fg='red',width=10,height=3,font=('Times new Roman',20))
b.grid(column=4,row=5)

d=Button(root,text='step2',bg='green',command=Parent.child,fg='red',width=10,height=3,font=('Times new Roman',20))
d.grid(column=4,row=6)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The step1 button creates an *instance* of `Parent`, but discards it immediately because the `Button` class uses the callback for its side effect, not its return value. `Parent.child` is an *unbound* method that expects an argument, but `Button` doesn't call its callback with any arguments. The callbacks for step1 and step2 will have to communicate via a global variable.

Answer (score 3):

The callback for step1 should create a global instance of `Parent` which the  callback for step2 can access.

```
def step1_callback():
    global p
    p = Parent()

def step2_callback():
    if p is not None:
        p.child()


p = None

b = Button(root, text='step1', bg='green', command=step1_callback, fg='red', width=10, height=3, font=('Times new Roman',20))

d = Button(root, text='step2', bg='green', command=step2_callback, fg='red', width=10, height=3, font=('Times new Roman',20))
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I am getting error at step 2, if i use instance then it executing
> step1 even before clicking the button.

The problem can be fix.

- Add namespace `from datetime import datetime`
- Comment in `instance = Parent()`. Noted, added capital 'P'
- Change `command=Parent.child, ..` to: command=instance.child,...

code:

```
instance = Parent()
:
:
d=Button(root,text='step2',bg='green',command=instance.child,fg='red',width=10,height=3,font=('Times new Roman',20))
```

Screenshot after before step 1, then step 1 and then step 2:

[image]